# Suppose $f$ is a real function satisfying $f(x+f(x))$ = $4f(x)$ and $f(1) = 4$. Then the value of $f(21)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Should I proceed with just putting the value of $f(1)=4$ in the first equation or there will be a different way of solving this ?

Comment: You will need to plug in only twice before finding what you seek.

Comment: With the amount of information you have, there is no other way than iterating.

Comment: Minimum effort is to try a few iterations "to see". In this case you don't need to go very far.

Comment: @Chappers: "no other way", are you sure ? Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are right.  You aren't given much, so use what you know.  Let $x=1$ in the first equation and what do you learn?  How does it help?

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $x = 1$ results that $f(5) = 16$. Now substitute $x = 5$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ f(1)=4 \\
f(1+f(1)) = f(5) = 4f(1) = 16, $$
and then $5+f(5)=21$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Replace $x$ by $x+f(x)$ in the original equation, which then becomes

$f(x+f(x)+f(x+f(x))) = 4f(x+f(x))$
i.e $f(x+f(x)+4f(x))=4*4f(x)$
i.e $f(x+5f(x))=16f(x)$

Setting $x=1$ and using the value $f(1)=4$ we get
$f(1+20)=f(21)=16*4=64$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ invertible, let us set $g=f^{-1}$, and
$$f(x+f(x))=4f(x)$$
can be rewritten as
$$f(g(y)+y)=4y,$$
then
$$g(y)+y=g(4y).$$
Setting $h(k)=g(4^k)$,
$$h(k+1)=h(k)+4^k,$$
which, with the initial condition $g(4)=h(1)=1$ is easily solved as
$$h(k)=\frac{4^k-1}3,$$
i.e.
$$g(y)=\frac{y-1}3,$$
or
$$\color{green}{f(x)=3x+1}.$$

As we can check,
$$3(x+(3x+1))+1=12x+4=4(3x+1).$$

---

More generally, the function can be defined for all reals by setting values arbitrarily in $(0,1]$ and using the fact that $$f(3^kx+\frac{4^k-1}3)=3^kf(x)+\frac{4^k-1}3$$
in other intervals, forming a self-similar plot.

[image]